# C++ implicit conversion does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, implicit-conversion

Been trying C++11 with g++ 5.3.1 for a while...
I thought I understood implicit conversion operators. Generally speaking,
if I define `Class3::operator Class2()` then I can pass a `Class3` *directly* into any function that takes a `Class2`. This seems
to work 99% of the time... But I have encountered a simple example where
this is not the case.

```
class Class1 {};

class Class2 {
public:
  inline friend Class1 & operator<<(Class1 & a, Class2 const& c)
  {return a;}
};

class Class3 {
public:
  inline operator Class2() const {return Class2();}
};

void Foo(Class2 c) {}

int main()
{
  Class1 c1;
  Class3 c3;

  // g++ does not like this:
  // error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'Class1' and 'Class3')
  // c1 << c3;

  // g++ likes these just fine:
  Foo(c3);
  c1 << Class2(c3);
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?
Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You haven't defined a `<<` operator overload for Class3, hence g++ doesn't like it. You convert Class3 `c3` into a Class2 which is a defined conversion operator you implemented. g++ likes that because you defined it. Be like g++.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Poriferous I do not see how that explains anything.

Comment: > What error message do you get

Comment: main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    main.cpp:19:6: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘Class1’ and ‘Class3’)
       c1 << c3;
          ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`friend` functions defined inside a class definition, without an out-of-class declaration, are visible only to argument-dependent lookup, and only if the class they are defined in is an *associated class* of one of the arguments.

`Class2` is not an associated class of `Class1` or `Class3`, and your `operator<<` isn't declared out-of-class, so it is not found by name lookup for `c1 << c3`. Without knowing that such an `operator<<` exists, the implicit conversion simply doesn't come into play.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to work in a small test:

`    inline Class1 & operator<<(Class1 & a, Class2 const& c)
    {return a;}`

Comment: OK, got it working in the main code branch I was working on too... Thank you, your answer is spot on. But, now, does anyone know WHY the language would have such an annoying restriction? To get my codebase working, I've had to move all the "operator<<" out of the classes, out of namespaces... doesn't this all go against any reasonable style recommendation?

Comment: When you say _associated_ do you mean "having direct inheritance"? There is some ambiguity on that term as applied to C++: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/255973/c-association-aggregation-and-composition]

Comment: @personal_cloud : "*I've had to move all the "operator<<" out of the classes, out of namespaces...*" They should not be out of namespaces, they should be in the same namespace as the type you're writing the operator for.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for explaining. It would be nice if there were some way to keep the "operator<<" within the namespace structure somehow, without breaking implicit conversions in later code. Imagine Class1, Class2, and Class3 are written at different times, and potentially frozen. It seems backward to require a lint tool that enforces putting "operator<<" *outside* the namespace even though it's really a feature of Class2.

Comment: @ildjarn No, tried that, it doesn't work. You have to pull it out of the namespace too. I suppose it might work if all 3 classes were in the same namespace. But not in general.

Comment: @personal_cloud : No, [you certainly do _not_ need to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/541f3f3a1216adb8), [nor should doing so work at all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23632527f52dd974). If I had to guess, not seeing your present code, I'd guess that you're defining each operator twice in different namespaces. Only _declare_ the `friend` and give a single definition and things will become more clear.

Comment: @iildjarn: try the following. namespace Class1 {
  class T {};
}

namespace Class2 {
  class T {};

inline Class1::T & operator<<(Class1::T & a, Class2::T const& c)
{return a;}
  // Moving this declaration/definition outside of "namespace Class2"
  // makes it work.
}


namespace Class3 {
  class T
  {
  public:
    inline operator Class2::T() const {return Class2::T();}
  };
}

void Foo(Class2::T c) {}

int main()
{
  Class1::T c1;
  Class3::T c3;

  // g++ does not like this:
  c1 << c3;

  // g++ likes these just fine:
  Foo(c3);
  c1 << Class2::T(c3);
}

Comment: @personal_cloud It seems like T.C has answered your question and beyond, is there a reason you've not accepted their answer?

Comment: @personal_cloud : In that code, there's still nothing to bring (the confusingly-named) `Class2` namespace into play; `c1 << c3` will look in the global namespace, `Class1` namespace, and `Class3` namespace. Putting the operator inside the global namespace is a _workaround_, yes, but a workaround for a poor design more than anything else. ;-] (And it deviates from the original question since it makes no use of `friend`, and `friend` definitions, by definition, go in the same namespace as the type they were declared in.)

Comment: @kfsone: sorry, only because I'm a stackoverflow newb and didn't realize I'm supposed to click the green checkmark. Accepted it now.

Comment: @ildjarn: Given the reference that T.C. has provided, I don't see how "friend" is going to be useful here.  Also I don't see how changing each Class to Class::T makes it into a poor design. Anyway, feel free to post better way to code the original example while keeping the "operator<<" within the Class2 declaration. (for either the class or namespace version of the question).

Comment: @personal_cloud : I didn't say friend would be useful here, I said that your question appears to be about friend and the code you've shown doesn't use it, and as such doesn't appear to be very relevant. ;-]